# Proof of statement about regularly varying distribution

Tags: limits, probability-theory

I am trying to find a proof of the following:

Proposition: Suppose $F$ is an absolutely continuous cdf with density $f$, and $F(x)>1$ for all $x \ge0 $ (infinite right extreme). Then

Suppose that for some $a>0$, 
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{xf(x)}{\overline{F}(x)}= a
$$
then $f$ is regularly varying with index $-(a+1)$, that is:
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(tx)}{f(x)}= t^{-(a+1)}
$$

I think the proof uses Karamata's Theorem, or a converse.

Karamata's theorem: If $f$ is regularly varying with index $a$ and $f$ is locally bounded on $[x_0,\infty]$, for some $x_0 \ge 0$, then, for $\alpha <-1$:
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\overline{F}(x)}{xf(x)} = \frac{-1}{a+1}
$$